# Use the first variable that isset()

Tags: php, arrays, get

I would like to set a position in an array to equal the first `$_GET` parameter that exists.

Here is the code I currently have which doesn't function exactly how I'd like as it uses arrays:

```
'searchOptions'=>array_merge(
                isset($_GET['Search1']['searchoption']) ? $_GET['Search1']['searchoption'] : array(),
                isset($_GET['Search2']['searchoption']) ? $_GET['Search2']['searchoption'] : array(),
                isset($_GET['Search3']['searchoption']) ? $_GET['Search3']['searchoption'] : array(),
                isset($_GET['Search4']['searchoption']) ? $_GET['Search4']['searchoption'] : array(),
                isset($_GET['searchBar']['searchoption']) ? $_GET['searchBar']['searchoption'] : array(),
                isset($_GET['searchOptions']) ? $_GET['searchOptions'] : array()
            ),
```

Is there a better way this can be done that avoids `array_merge` and works properly? Currently right now it does not work if a string is passed in the `$_GET` parameter as it needs to be an array.

The way this works is that only one of the `$_GET` variables being checked will ever exist at one time, as such once there is one that isset the rest of them are irrelevant.

Is there a way to just do something similar to what I have but without treating it like I am merging arrays?

This could be broken up into many if statements that check and then set if it exists but it seems quite clunky.

Comment: As you can see, this is a horrible way of doing this.  Rethink your get parameters and do it differently.

Comment: @AbraCadaver that would be nice, but unfortunately that is not an option in this case, I have to work with $_GET parameters like this. I have renamed some of them from their more sane names to make it more readable and less specific.

Comment: Are the values of these parameters supposed to be strings or arrays? Or can they be either?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP >= 7.0 you can use the [Null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) and chain them:

```
$options =  $_GET['Search1']['searchoption']   ??
            $_GET['Search2']['searchoption']   ??
            $_GET['Search3']['searchoption']   ??
            $_GET['Search4']['searchoption']   ??
            $_GET['searchBar']['searchoption'] ??
            $_GET['searchOptions']             ?? [];
```

If none are set then `$options` is an empty array `[]`, if that's not what you want just replace it.

Comment: You beat me to it, I've been trying to find the documentation page to link to.

Comment: I don't think you should have `[]` at the end of the chain.

Comment: That's the default empty array if none of the vars are set.  Edited so hopefully it's more clear.